# Evaluating $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-|x|} e^{-i k x} d x , \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I will like to find the complex coefficients of the Fourier series for $f(x)=e^{-|x|},x\in [-\pi,\pi]$:
$$
c_{k}(f):=\left\langle f, e_{k}\right\rangle=
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-|x|} e^{-i k x} d x =
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-|x|-ikx} d x
, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

I tried $u$-substitution: $u(x)=-|x|-ikx$. I got $c_k(f)=0,\forall k$. This is clearly not right.

I was thinking whether I could use the fact $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ikx} d x = \delta_{k,0},k \in\mathbb{Z}$? I was lucky to be able to use this in some other problems but I can se a way to use it here. Any help is welcome.

Kind regards,

Comment: Split the integral in to integrals over $(-\pi, 0)$ and $(0, \pi)$. The calculations are then  straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I'm an idiot. I did this but then I integrated it wrong :D I will try again. Thanks!

Comment: Why shouldn't the endpoints of the interval not be included?  @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Values at the end points have no effect on the integrals.

Comment: Yes, I know. But $f$ is defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Any time you have absolute values (or any other function that is defined piecewise in terms of nicer functions), you should break your interval up into parts for each region where your function is defined differently (unless there is something like symmetry that you can exploit to avoid doing a full integral).

Comment: Good advice @Aaron. I can't see whether there is symmetri or not.? I can not plot it either so It's heard to se just by looking at it.

Comment: @Xenusi Well, $|x|$ is an even function, and $e^{-ikx}=\cos (kx) - i \sin (kx)$ has an even real part but an odd imaginary part, and you're integrating over a symmetric interval (something of the form $[-a,a]$), so symmetry says the imaginary part will cancel and the real part will be twice what you would get if you integrated over $[0,a]$.  But I didn't mean for this particular example, just in general, there are times when you have information involving symmetry or periodicity or whatever that simplifies things, and it is convenient to use them before you do other unraveling.

Answer (score 1):

The real part of the integrand is even, and the imaginary part is odd, giving a real integral.

Then

$$\int_0^{\pi}e^{-x-ikx}dx=\left.\frac{e^{-x-ikx}}{-1-ik}\right|_0^\pi=\left.\frac{e^{-\pi-ik\pi}-1}{-1-ik}\right|_0^\pi=-\frac{(-1)^ke^{-\pi}-1}{1+k^2}(1-ik)$$

and finally

$$I=\frac{1-(-1)^ke^{-\pi}}{\pi(1+k^2)}.$$

Comment: Do you use some kind of symmetry ?

Comment: @Xenusi: did you read the first sentence ?

Comment: yes, but I can not see how this is relevant or useful to notice? realising that the integral is real can also be obtained just by calculating it.

Comment: @Xenusi: do you know what even an odd mean ?

Comment: Only be definition and nothing else.

Comment: @Xenusi: ponder why I mentioned this.

Comment: Oh, so the integrand is even. Therefore one can use symmetry. So I could just calculate $$
\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-x-i k x} d x
$$ and multiple with $2$ at the end. Then I have evaluated 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-|x|-i k x} d x, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$. Right?

Comment: @Xenusi: exactly. And drop the imaginary part.

Comment: What do you mean by drop the imaginary part and where?

Comment: Also, by integrand you a referring to $$
e^{-|x|-i k x}
$$ and not

$$
e^{-x-i k x}
$$
?